Stuck Bolt — After heating with torch, use unburnt propane to cool?
I've used a propane torch or a Map-Pro torch to heat up a stuck bolt or nut.
Some related comments from @fraxinus in Welded nut on stuck/broken bolt — Let it completely cool for an hour or more?

From the answer:
Heating the inner detail (bolt remnants) expands it more than the surrounding material that is relatively colder. When the bolt cools down it gets loose.
Some also try cooling it even lower with liquid propane (whatever it is called when sold in a spray can) thus improving the chances.

From a comment:
Just get a can of "compressed air" - the thing that is used for removing the dust from hard-to-reach electronics. It is either propane or some coolant (e.g. R134a). When sprayed with the valve down [the can upside down], it sprays very cold liquid instead of a gas. Sometimes it is sold as "cooling spray" and the whole thing is designed to spray liquid with the valve up [the can upright]. When the liquid reaches some surface, it evaporates and carries away some heat. Temperatures as low as -20C can be reached. Propane is still flammable and the due care has to be taken.

It sounds like air dusters can be used to cool down a heated bolt, loosening the bolt further.
To clarify, can a propane or Map-Pro torch be used as well, without igniting the fuel, just letting the unburnt fuel hit the hot bolt?
Of course, there are safety risks with with unburnt propane: risk of explosion as well as asphyxiation (if I recall, propane displaces the air in the lungs because it is heavier than air). I'm just trying to understand what is normally done/what is moderately safe.
It would be handy if the same torch that was used to heat up the bolt could also be used to cool the bolt, without needing to buy separate air dusters.

Despite the safety ishues, It won't be a good way to achieve what you want. The torch after use it it will be hot, and the next gas release will be warmed
